# Cant find documentation about lwm2m / wakaama

Tags: lwm2m

I am trying to find accessible information about the lwm2m stack. I am currently looking into wakaama. Unfortunately, I am not able to find any information except a few example applications in the wakaama stack. Not even a API reference!

By the way, I feel that the example in wakaama are quite convoluted and not helpful where I am now.

So, (1) why is the information about wakaama so bad and (2) is there a good source of information?

Comment: Maybe you are looking also for the [official LwM2M documentation](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/release/LightweightM2M/Lightweight_Machine_to_Machine-v1_1-OMASpecworks.pdf)? Or just for the wakaama api guide?

Comment: In the latter case, you are asking for an external resources, so the only answer would be a link and... you know, links expire. SO is more suitable for specific questions. Do you have any?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think this is helpful for an overall understanding. Sorry, I do not have a specific technical question.

Comment: Achieving an overall understanding is for sure a good start. Regarding Wakaama, you are probably right when you write it is poorly documented. I could not find a good API description.

Comment: Thanks again. The API reference/manual might be useful, if I could find it :)

Comment: I agree with your findings. To improve it, I created [an issue to improve this situation](https://github.com/eclipse/wakaama/issues/586), and me (and others) will probably work on it in the near future. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: @rettichschnidi Thank you for the initiative, that hopefully will lead to improvements!